# WorkSheet_change event doesn't fire on pressing enter, but tab works on drop-down change

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have wrote code in `worksheet_change` event but this event doesn't fire when I press enter but It works well on pressing tab.

I have drop-down in excel worksheet cell.

Could someone please find solution for this?

You can find the file here. [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13yBeUSxIhLeRDbRC2SUHE5Lgqi2iU0bG)

Comment: If you double click into a cell in the change range, and then press enter, does it work ?

Comment: *doesn't fire when I press enter*...pressing Enter doesn't constitute a change. What exactly are you doing before you press Enter that should trigger the Change event?

Comment: Share the code you are using with the Sheet !

Comment: I change the text in cell then press enter the event doesn't raise but when press tab it does

Comment: When I use the following, I get a printed result when I enter a value in a cell and press either Tab or Enter. Both work.  `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "cell " & Target.Address & " changed"
End Sub`

Comment: @PeterT I am using the same it works when type in simple cell but it doesn't work on dropdown type cell.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem, what's version of Excel do you use? How do you create the drop down list in file? I suggest you provide a sample Workbook about your problem.

Comment: I created drop-down by using VBA and excel version is 2016.

Comment: The file is uploaded and I have shared link in question please find